# Javascript Probability Selector Based on Factors Random Number Generator

Tags: javascript, probability

I've developed the below to select pauseA 80% of the time, pauseB 15% of the time, and pauseC 5% of the time. I'm new at javascript and I don't know what's wrong with the code

```
function pauseGenerator() {
  //random pause between 10 and 20 seconds
  var pauseA = 10000 + Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
  
  //random pause between 20 and 40 seconds
  var pauseB = 20000 + Math.floor(Math.random()*20000);
  
  //random pause between 60 and 90 seconds
  var pauseC = 60000 + Math.floor(Math.random()*30000);

  //percentage chance of each pause
  var factorA = .80;
  var factorB = .15;
  var factorC = .05;
    
  var randomNo = Math.floor(Math.random());
  var selectedPause;
  
  if (randomNo <= factorA) {
    selectedPause = pauseA;
  } else if (randomNo > factorA and randomNo <= (factorA + factorB)) {
    selectedPause = pauseB;
  } else if (randomNo > (factorA + factorB)) {
    selectedPause = pauseC;
  }

  return selectedPause;
}
```

Comment: You cant use ``and`` keyword in JavaScript as there is no ``and`` in JavaScript, the correct representation for **and** in JavaScript is ``&&(Logical AND)`` or ``&(Bitwise AND)``

Comment: Thanks. I changed the `and` to `&&` and also removed the last `if` and just said `else { selectedPause = pauseC; }` but it still doesn't appear to be woring

Comment: Can you edit your question with the latest code and what exactly the issue you are facing?

Comment: I figured out it was working fine - the place I was using it didn't allow for a function so I just removed the 'function() {}' portion and it executed beautifully. Thanks